# How to make puppeteer grab a dynamic class attribute and it textContent from an element on a page

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

am trying to scrape the content of a particular Div tag from a gamming website.
at first when you visit the site the div tag will have empty content with uncompleted class.
example

```
<div class="ball ball-"><div>
```

then after every 45seconds the textContent and the class attribute will be dynamically added
example

```
    <div class="ball ball-red">45<div>
```

after every 45 seconds the textContent and the class attribute will change to another value.

At first it might look like this

```
 <div class="ball ball-red">23<div>
```

after 45 seconds it will change maybe to something like this

```
 <div class="ball ball-green">3<div>
```

after another 45 seconds it may look like this

```
    <div class="ball ball-blue">33<div>
```

How can i make puppeteer to visit such page, wait for the class and the textcontent to be added to the div tag, and then grab whatever the class is also grab the textcontent & log it to console close puppetter and run it again.

I tried the below code and keep telling me selectElemClass is not defined or cannot read property length of undefined. please help.

you can inspect the result of the 6 ball on the page to see the behaviour am trying to explain.
here is the [website url](https://logigames.bet9ja.com/Games/Launcher?gameId=11000&provider=0&sid=&pff=1&skin=201)
Am just trying to get the class and text context of the firstball starting from the left. if i can succesfully get that to work, then i will repeat the same working process for the rest 5 balls.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeData(url){
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
const selectElemClass = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelectorAll(".ball")[2].classList[1];
});
//console.log(selectElemClass);
const hasClassArived = await page.waitForFunction(function(selectElemClass){
   return selectElemClass.length > 6;
},{timeout:60000});
hasClassArived ? console.log(selectElemClass) : console.log("failed");
browser.close();
}
scrapeData("https://logigames.bet9ja.com/Games/Launcher?gameId=11000&provider=0&sid=&pff=1&skin=201");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeData(url){
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  await page.waitForFunction(() => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(".ball")[2].innerText !== '';
  }, { timeout: 60000 });

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const ball = document.querySelectorAll(".ball")[2];
    return {
      number: ball.innerText,
      color: ball.classList[1].split('-')[1],
    };
  });
  console.log(data);

  browser.close();
}
scrapeData("https://logigames.bet9ja.com/Games/Launcher?gameId=11000&provider=0&sid=&pff=1&skin=201");
```